# Meteorjs load html script resource in template (not in body)

Tags: javascript, meteor, jsplumb

I am using the jsplumbtoolkit framework in order to load in several script html templates into my meteorjs application in order to create the appropriate divs/dialogues options necessary as a part of the api.  After some troubleshooting I determined the issue seemed to be that Meteorjs was not loading my html script through the onRendered function that I supplied it with.

To give you a better idea of the problem

//Due to Meteorjs not able to load scripts directly in the template, I added the script load to my onRendered function in my template js

```
Template.mytemplate.onRendered(function(){

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type="text/x-jtk-templates";
        script.src = "templates/workflowtemplate.html";
        $("#rulesscripttemplate").replaceWith(script);
    });
})
```

workflowtemplate.html is in the appropriate meteorjs directory /public/templates/workflowtemplate.html and I am assuming the directory is correct.

This is properly loaded when I check my client Mozilla developer kit as well

```
<script type="text/x-jtk-templates" src="templates/templaterulesworkflow.html"></script>
```

Is there a better way to confirm that this resource was infact loaded to the client through mozilla?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  had to add the `<script type="text/x-jtk-templates" src="templates/templaterulesworkflow.html"></script>` to the  tag of my application.  That resolved the issue.